# Why does SuperDevMode only provides LogLevel SEVERE?

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt, logging

I use GWT 2.7 and want to provide logging with Level INFO and WARNUNG in my app. In my gwt.xml file I have:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/> 
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>
```

It works perfect in Dev mode but in SuperDevMode I only get Log level SEVERE to be logged.

**Why does SuperDevMode only provides LogLevel SEVERE?**

Comment: what do you mean with LogLevel SERVE ? could be SEVERE?

Comment: I mean SEVERE it was a spelling errog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked one of my applications (which uses GXT) and there I see the log message:

[image]

I use this lines inside my module descriptor:

```
 <!-- values are:  severe, warning, info, config, fine, finer, finest -->
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
 <!-- Write messages to browser consoles and to the jvm and dev mode -->
 <!-- Note that these are the defaults, so we don’t actually need to list them -->
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.systemHandler" value="ENABLED"/>
 <!-- Leave RPC logging disabled, as we aren’t setting that up in this example -->
 <set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="DISABLED"/>
 <!-- Ask GXT to log all internal details -->
 <set-property name="gxt.logging.enabled" value="true"/>
```

and add this code to my presenter:

```
private static final Logger logger = logger.getLogger(ShellPresenter.class.getName());

logger.log(Level.INFO, "Starting module Hermes");
```

I don't spent time to find out which one of the configurations enables logging nor if it is related to GXT.

And some more informations:

[groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/BRZNt1_qEjg](http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/BRZNt1_qEjg)

Comment: I accept your answer but you should point out that the key is this line: ``<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />``

Answer (score 1):

To change log level in SDM, add this option to command line when running it:

```
-logLevel (ERROR|WARN|INFO|TRACE|DEBUG|SPAM|ALL)
```