# GWT Logger: No control over debug output?

Tags: java, logging, gwt

I'm having the following in my **client.gwt.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN" "http://gwtproject.org/doctype/2.7.0/gwt-module.dtd">
<module rename-to='client'>

    <inherits name="com.mz.client.app" />

    <source path="client"/>

    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINER"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>
    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/>

</module>
```

and I'm trying to log the following:

```
    LOGGER.info("INFO");
    LOGGER.fine("FINE");
    LOGGER.warning("WARNING");
    LOGGER.severe("SEVERE");
```

but the only thing that shows up in my firebug console is the SEVERE message:

> ```
> Mon Sep 07 13:44:09 GMT+200 2015 com.mz.client.App 
> SEVERE: SEVERE
> ```

Why am I not getting the other log messages?

---

I have already set the `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level` in `logging.properties` to `FINE`:

```
# Limit the message that are printed on the console to INFO and above.
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

---

**Edit:**

Right now it is working even without one of those lines

```
<!--    <set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINER"/> -->
<!--    <set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/>  -->
<!--    <set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED"/> -->
```

I removed those lines, cleaned my project and launched the Apache server and for whatever magical reason I am receiving debug output.

Changing

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="FINER"/>
```

to

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>
```

does not change the output. I am getting all messages down to `FINER`. Setting

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="FALSE"/>
```

now does not remove the debug output. Still getting everything.

I want to have control over my debug output..

Comment: Hope it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660021/why-does-superdevmode-only-provides-loglevel-severe/28660660#28660660

Comment: @ElHoss Hi! Thanks for the link but it appears that my `.gwt.xml` file is getting completely ignored. At the moment I am getting debug output - no idea why though - but I can't turn it off now and I have not control over the debug level ..

Comment: Perhaps the logging.properties file that you mention is conflicting with something within GWT. I don't think it should be used.

Comment: Can you add the full gwt.xml file, gwt version? Are you getting this problem with DevMode or SuperDevMode or production mode?

Comment: @Mohit There is not much to add, but I've put it to my question.

Comment: @LINEMAN78 I just started my server and Eclipse and right now the logging doesn't work anymore XD it's crazy.. I don't know why and what is happening but there is something strange happening ..

Comment: @StefanFalk How about some more info on your setup. Which web server? Which browser? DevMode, SuperDev or Production? If you are looking to firebug for the logging you may need to add the `gwt.logging.firebugHandler'

Comment: I think you should inherit Logging module first and then com.mz.client.app. If you put a breakpoint in your module and GWT logging module, logging will be called later (with current config). Hence, your module code is executed with default logging config.

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your **module.gwt.xml**:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />
```

[image]

Comment: Check! Thank you! But any idea why `<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="INFO"/>` is not working? I am still getting `FINER` and `FINE` level messages .. :/

Comment: Okay, I am not sure if this was the solution. Removing `<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE" />` still works for me right now - no idea why but it does even without that line.

Comment: Try not to use `logging.properties` file and in `module.gwt.xml` use only `gwt.logging.logLevel` property. That should be enough according to [GWT Documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html).

Comment: How can I *not* use this file? I've set it back to default `.level= INFO` and `java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE`. Only using `gwt.logging.logLevel` does not change anything unfortunately. I don't know what exactly goes on here .. :/

Comment: I mean: make it as simple as possible. There is a minimal example in [GWT documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html). Just inherit `com.google.gwt.logging.Logging` and use `gwt.logging.logLevel` property to control debug output. Nothing more should be necessary.